# Arrays in node-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I'm attemping to leverage [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap) to make a SOAP request containing an array. Requests without arrays seem to work fine however when attempting to pass an array I'm receiving the error 'not an ARRAY reference' from the server.

Any idea? My script is as follows:

```
var soap = require('soap');

var url = 'http://example.com/example.wsdl';

var args = {
    email: 'example',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    series: {
        element: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    }
};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if(err) throw err;

    client.ExampleMethod(args, function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Mr.Robot When I first posted this question five years ago I gave up. `node-soap` simple wasn’t mature enough at the time. I haven’t used SOAP since, so I can’t testify to the maturity of the package anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No idea what the code you're calling is supposed to do, but just guessing from the name "series", are you sure that a thing called "series" is supposed to contain an array named "element", rather than be the array?

Comment: Because the array is ultimately being reformed into XML for the SOAP request the `element` object seems to need to exist as an object containing an array in order to set the name of the actual (`<element>a</element><element>b</element>`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
series: {
    element: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}
```

Comment: I made some modifications (remove the braces, these are for objects), then this works perfectly 

Comment: oh also, I noticed that you can either use a single element in place of the array: `element: 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

This is currently being discussed [over at the GitHub repository (issue #143)](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/143).

tldr; The collaborators are trying to determine how they should convert JSON to XML. Which relates to [issue #368](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/368).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.